# Get weekly dates on Monday, Friday, X times

Tags: php

I want to find out next X dates based on weekly repetition. For example, today's date is 8th May, 2023, i want to find out next 4 dates for Monday & Friday (i.e. Weekly on Monday, Friday, 4 times)

So expected result will be:

8th May, 2023

12th May, 2023

15th May, 2023

19th May, 2023

```
        $appointment_start_date = "2023-05-08";
        $all_appointments[] = [
            'appointment_date' => $appointment_start_date
        ];
        $post['weekly_day'] = ["Monday", "Friday"];
        $recurrence_end_after = 4;
        // Create a new DateTime object
        $date = new \DateTime($appointment_start_date);
        
        for ($i=1; $i<=$recurrence_end_after; $i++) {
            foreach ($post['weekly_day'] as $weekly_day) {
                 if ($i > $recurrence_end_after) {
                     break;
                 }
                // Modify the date it contains
                $date->modify('next ' . $weekly_day);

                // Output
                $appointment_start_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
                $all_appointments[] = [
                    'appointment_date' => $appointment_start_date
                ];
                $i++;
            }
        }
```

But this snippet doesn't return the expected result. It just return

2023-05-08, 2023-05-15, 2023-05-19, 2023-05-22 so it skips the Friday date (i.e. 12th May, 2023)

### Few more examples

Input: 1st June, 2023.
recurrence_end_after: 6.
weekly_day: Monday, Friday.
Expected output:

- 1st June, 2023
- 2nd June, 2023
- 5th JUne, 2023
- 9th June, 2023
- 12th June, 2023
- 19th June, 2023

Input: 10th May, 2023.
recurrence_end_after: 4.
weekly_day: Saturday, Sunday
Expected Output:

- 10th May, 2023
- 13th May, 2023
- 14th May, 2023
- 19th May, 2023

Comment: Please test this script under a few different realistic scenarios in your application and see if you can find any ways to break it.  https://3v4l.org/Vq6hr  If you cannot break it, I'll post an answer.  I am afraid there is some ambiguity in your solitary test case.

Comment: @mickmackusa It will break if appointment start date is 1st June, 2023

Comment: Also i am trying to find the recursion including appointment start date. Similar to how google calendar does except it will include appointment start date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (or better, examples) so that answers can be validated as correct/incorrect.  Your question is not clear about what to expect if the start date is Thursday 1 June 2023 and the two days are Monday and Friday. (You don't need "recursion", just loops.)

Comment: I have added few more examples, so basically start from start date and then get all dates after that start date for which those day appears. So for 1 June, find next dates for all Monday, Friday but in this case Friday is appear immediately so it should add that. Also added some more examples, hope it will clarify it. So It's not like Monday after Friday. It depends on date so Friday might appear before Monday. Non english speaker, i hope you will get the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$appointment_start_date = "2023-05-08";
$all_appointments[] = [
    'appointment_date' => $appointment_start_date
];
$post['weekly_day'] = ["Monday", "Friday"];
$recurrence_end_after = 4;

// Create a new DateTime object
$date = new \DateTime($appointment_start_date);

// get next 7 weekdays
$sorted_weekly_day = [];
$date_interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {
    $sorted_weekly_day[] = $date->add($date_interval)->format('l');
}

// Set weekly days in the right order
$post['weekly_day'] = array_intersect($sorted_weekly_day, $post['weekly_day']);

// Create a new DateTime object (again)
$date = new \DateTime($appointment_start_date);

$i = 0;

while ($i<=$recurrence_end_after) {
    foreach ($post['weekly_day'] as $weekly_day) {
        if ($i > $recurrence_end_after) {
            break;
        }
        // Modify the date it contains
        $date->modify('next ' . $weekly_day);

        // Output
        $appointment_start_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $all_appointments[] = [
            'appointment_date' => $appointment_start_date
        ];
        $i++;
    }
}
```